# Cypress - How to make an assertion on element depending on page we are land in?

Tags: cypress, chai

In my test i have four links. Each of them redirect to the different page. After redirection I have page with breadcrubms. In my test I would like to assert that after redirection the breadcrumbs contain specific text which are defined in fixtures. How can I made it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom Cypress command to validate your breadcrumbs, and drive the behavior based on the url yielded by `cy.url()`.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('validateBreadcrumbs', () => {
  cy.url().then((url) => {
    if (url === 'foo') {
      // some code
    } else if (url === 'bar') {
      // some other code
    } else {
      // some other code
    }
  });
});

// in a test
it('test', () => {
  // code to hit the re-direct
  cy.validateBreadcrumbs();
});
```

That being said, it may just be simpler and more direct to not have an abstracted function, and just validate the text as you normally would after the re-direction.